# How does changing 'Dimensions' fields at once exactly work?

Tags: modeling, interface

For related X, Y, Z fields of Location, Rotation  and Scale in the Transform panel of the 3D view 'N-Region', there is a possibility to change the 3 fields at once. It can be done with the mouse or with numerical input.

[image]

But it seems 'Dimensions' fields behave strangely (entering individual values works as expected). Sometimes the value is lost after being entered, sometimes only two fields are changed. An example:

[image]

- When using the mouse, Y is left unchanged (expected: All values adjusted in proportion).
- The final dimensions X and Z are different (expected: Final values are starting values times the same factor).
- When entering the value 5, the result is 2 (expected: 5, whatever the scale value).

Is this a bug?
If not, what is the reason to prevent this single input?

Using 2.79b.

Comment: Good catch, Probably classified as a bug or over site.   `C.object.dimensions = (5, 5, 5)` in py console works as expected.

Comment: It is not a bug, it is a known limitation, dimensions values are actually a hack and don't work with click-drag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug, it is a [well known limitation](https://developer.blender.org/search/query/tvxH4.XewwYR/#R) of the current system, as you can see in the [bug repot](https://developer.blender.org/T38587).

> Object dimensions are broken and an abuse of RNA, IMHO - the same
>   problem happens from Python and we had it reported too.
>
> Basically they rely on one axis being set, then updating - before the
>   other values are set.

Comment: Thanks. A more recent activity [here](https://developer.blender.org/T54771). Too bad the UI allows something that is known to be broken. RNA presentation can be found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961557/what-is-an-rna-or-dna-property).