# Is there a way to make the scale an actual representation of the measure system (metric) I use?

Tags: scale, units

I don't know why this is made as it is because it's totally not making ANY sense and broken as well. Why is scale a multiplication factor instead of a representation of real world values? [Metric system:] Why is a cube 2 meters at a scale of one?
I chose metric and set the unit scale to 0.5 so it would actually be what I enter it to be, but this blender is doing what it wants. First it acts like I want. Doing a cube of 20 x 12 x 1 meter works. Then I save everything open the project up a day later and when I add a second cube of the same size, it's not the same size as the object I created a day before. Even though the settings are still the same (metric and unit scale of 0.5). I can't believe that crap. i mean I understand it in a game engine like unity or unreal engine to be a factor instead of a unit, but not in a 3D modelling tool -.-

what is also not understandable is that when I create a cube of height (z) 4, I actually have to put in 4 into the location z field so it is on top of the grid even though the origin is in it's middle. so actually shouldn't i have to enter for the location just 2...

Is there any way to correct this so scale can actually be set in meters instead of a multiplication factor??? Can't understand that implementation at all, especially annoying when it's not working as it should

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119575/why-is-blenders-default-cube-2-cubic-meters-instead-of-1)

Answer (score 2):

If you set up a unit scale for Blender, inputs will parse the strings you enter in any field which expects length.

Supposing you have set the units to meters, and the Unit Scale to .5 (at least, in my build)..

- If you enter '1', Blender will *always* interpret that as 1 Blender Unit (50cm)
- If you enter '1m' Blender will interpret that as 1 meter
- You can enter '25cm' or '250mm' or '.25m' etc. to refer to that length
- If you enter '1in' Blender will interpret that as 1 inch. Because you have declared your dimensions to be in meters, that will be translated to 2.54cm
- You can even enter an expression like '25m / 4' to get 6.25 meters

I'm open to correction, but it *is* true that the last-used radius for object creation can not be made to persist in the .blend file, and reverts to 1 of your declared base unit when you reopen it. However, the last creation size requested (in the tool region) *does* persist within sessions, on a per-primitive basis.

These are deliberate choices on the part of the developers, not careless. There are many choices in Blender that I don't personally agree with, but in the vast majority of cases, if I stop to think about them, I can see the arguments for the choices having been made that way. Usually it's to do with 'cleanliness'.. i.e. consistency between different parts of what is, after all,  a large application. I have been pleasantly surprised by that consistency in Blender's way of thinking, compared to many proprietary applications, especially those with a long history of accretions .. :)

Answer (score 1):

The system is not broken in any way and is working as intended and it also makes perfect sense.

*Scale* is the size of an object compared to itself. If you have a tennis ball of standard size or in other words one that has a scale of one standard tennis ball and you want to redefine its size and make it twice as big, you can enter 2 in all scale fields to get a ball precisely twice the size of a standard tennis ball. Notice that I can participate in this whole situation without having a clue about what the actual dimensions of a standard tennis ball are in centimeters or any other units, because it's irrelevant. Scale property exists only for this purpose - for you to be able to redefine object's size in relation to its original size. It has nothing to do with units or any measurement systems and is intended to be like that. There is nothing wrong with it, the whole concept of scale in Blender(and pretty much in all other 3d applications) is like that.

What you want scale to be is **dimensions**:

[image]

Well - it is not. *Dimenstions* are a different thing. Only they define the size of an object in relation to a specific measurement unit and unlike scale not in relation to the object's own original size.

If you adjust the *scale* of an object for it to have the *dimensions* you want or if you adjust the dimensions of the object this way changing the scale and then decide that this should be the new original scale of this object, you can apply the scale with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> -> Scale:

[image]

I would like to advise to keep an open mind and try to understand how things work first assuming that they are working as intended. Searching for the reason and explanation why things are working the way they are as opposed to getting angry at them for not matching your expectations may be extremely valuable when learning to work with complex 3d software like Blender.

Comment: There _is_ a disappointment, here, in my build, anyway.. in any other field-set, I can left-swipe the set, and enter, say '.5m' in all of them simultaneously. For some reason, in the 'Dimensions' set, that doesn't work. I have to enter the values one at a time. I can't think why... do you think that's a bug? No exception is thrown..

Comment: Now that frustration I do understand. I would consider it a bug. It seems to me that functionality does not work as intended or as it works in other parts of the interface. It is like that for as long as I can remember as well and it doesn't seem to be fixed in 2.8 yet. I think this should be reported as a bug.

Comment: Since you confirm you can reproduce that, I'll go ahead and make a report. The 'Dimensions' set is unusual, in that it has to update another set in the interface: ('Scale').. I suspect that might have something to do with it....

Comment: I think you will be doing a very good job for all of us by reporting it. And I also hope it catches some developer's attention, it would be great to sort out all the little things like that in Blender.

Comment: @RobinBetts recommend not reporting. Has come up before, one of the issues mysteriously known as a  "_known limitation_"

Comment: Oh yes, a known limitation... If reported enough times 'known limitations' can evolve into bugs and get fixed.

Comment: Hello Everyone, Hello Martin Z. Thank you so much for this superb answer to my question!!!! I was a little frustrated as I tried to create a duplication of the store I'm working for for a small mini game and could never figure out that there were actually dimension settings like in your picture! I'll investigate as soon as I have the time to get these showing in my blender environment. Thanks a lot for your effort!!! :D

Comment: Nonetheless, thanks @batFINGER .. I'll confirm it's been reported previously...

Comment: It seems its [already reported](https://developer.blender.org/T54771). It is confirmed as a bug. I can find nothing about it being any serious limitation.

Comment: @RobinBetts [The link I was searching for](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116658/how-does-changing-dimensions-fields-at-once-exactly-work)